# Implementing QuickSort With middle element as Pivot

Tags: java, pivot, quicksort

I tried and wrote a code for Quicksort with middle element as pivot.

I was successful in writing one.

But Pivot has the property that:

Elements on its left are lesser than pivot and greater on its right.

I was not able to achieve this in my following code.

```
private static void QuickSortAlgorithm(int[] a, int i, int n) 
{
    if(i<n)
    {
        int part = partition(a,i,n);

        QuickSortAlgorithm(a, i, part-1);

        QuickSortAlgorithm(a, part, n);
    }
}

private static int partition(int[] a, int i, int n) 
{
    int pivot = (i+n)/2;

    int left = i;

    int right = n;
    while(left<=right)
    {
        while(a[left]<a[pivot]){
            left++;
        }

        while(a[right]>a[pivot])
        {
            right--;
        }

        if(left<=right)
        {
            swap(a,left,right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return left;

}
```

Main Method:

```
    int a[]={5,7,3,9,1};
    int n = a.length;
    QuickSortAlgorithm(a,0,n-1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

My doubt is:

I am sending left as my partitioned index.

But, when I am recursively calling QuickSortAlgorithm()

I am sending `i to part-1` and `part to n`;

What should I send as partition index so that

I could call something like this: So that pivot property is satisfied?

```
    QuickSortAlgorithm(a, i, part-1);

    QuickSortAlgorithm(a, part+1, n);
```

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

you have to send pivot value in first stack call inclusive and pivot+1 as lower index for second stack call.
You also have to put value of left as i+1 then your code will give an correct output

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the return value to left+1 in partition method.

Try this program:

```
import java.io.*;
public class QuickSort {

public int partion(int[] a, int l, int h) {

    int middle = (h+l)/2;
    //System.out.println(middle);
    int pivot = a[middle];
    int i = l;
    int j = h;

    while (i <= j) {
        while (a[i] < pivot) i++;
        while (a[j] > pivot) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(a, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
          
        }
    }
   // swap(a,i,j);
    System.out.println((i+j)/2);
    return i-1;
}

public void quick(int[] a, int l, int h) {
        if (l<h) {
            int pi = partion(a, l, h);
            System.out.println(pi);
            if (l < pi - 1)
                quick(a, l, pi+1);
            if (pi < h)
                quick(a, pi+1, h);
        }
    }

public void swap(int[] a, int l, int h){
    int temp=a[l];
    a[l]=a[h];
    a[h]=temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {10,80,30,90,40,50,70};
    int l=0;
    int h=a.length-1;

    QuickSort q =new QuickSort();
    q.quick(a,0,h);
    System.out.println(" Sorted Array : ");
    for(int e :a){
       System.out.print(e+" , ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can choose the leftmost element in the array or you can choose any random element to be your pivot.

Check out the [wikipedia page on quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) for more details about choosing pivot

Comment: He wants to choose the middle element as the pivot, not the first nor the last!